# How to get a random char from a string

Tags: string, rust

I have a string and I want to get a random character from it. It should hopefully work like this:

```
fn main() {
    let words = "helloworld";
    let mut result = String::new();
    // get random char and append to result
    println!("result is {}", result);
}
```

I have tried using `rand::seq::sample_iter` on `words.chars`.

Comment: *I have tried using rand::seq::sample_iter on words.chars* — and what happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
extern crate rand; // 0.6.0

use rand::seq::IteratorRandom;

fn main() {
    let words = "helloworld";
    let mut result = String::new();

    let random = words
        .chars()
        .choose(&mut rand::thread_rng())
        .expect("Couldn't get random char");

    result.push(random);

    println!("result is {}", result);
}
```